# Copy folder structure on Windows except for one folder with files

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

I need to copy folder structure without files except for one sub-folder. That is I want to copy the folder structure without files plus only one of the sub-folder to be copied with its content.

I can accomplish folder structure copy using

```
xcopy /t /e "source folder" "destination folder"
```

But I want a folder like `data` in source folder to be copied with its content to destination folder. I have to do it with a single line of code. Is that possible?

Comment: and why is adding another `xcopy` command after the first one bad? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Comment: I am not saying it is bad. I just asked, can it be accomplished in a single line?

Comment: Be very careful of the destination folder when using `robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /mir /xd FOLDER_TO_EXCLUDE` It mirrors everything from source to destination so if you already have some other files in the destination that are not present in source, they will get purged. Not even going to recycle bin, completely deleted. I just managed to permanently delete a bunch of useful files. GG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx):

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /mir /xd FOLDER_TO_EXCLUDE
```